# speeding up WebGL readPixels for picking

Tags: webgl

I am implementing GLSL picking, which relies on readPixels() to get single pixel data.

My first attempt was to simply draw color map (1x1 pixel) on the screen, read the pixel, then draw over it.
That sadly results in fps drop from solid 60 to 30-40.

After some googling, i found out the problem was caused by synchronisation between CPU and GPU. So i tried rendering in offscreen buffer as described here
http://coffeesmudge.blogspot.com/2013/08/implementing-picking-in-webgl.html

but it seems that it doesn't change anything - i still read from the buffer while it is in use (it has to be active for readPixels to work).

So my question - can i somehow read from the offscreen buffer while it is not in use?

Answer (score 0):

You might use multiple render targets:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_draw_buffers/

In that way you could attach your current frame buffer to color attachment 0, and an extra picking buffer in color attachment 1. In the extra buffer you might write the picking information (e.g., object id).

Since everything is done (scene rendering and rendering the picking buffer) in a single pass, the overhead should be minimally.